# Lambda and DynamoDB: is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:UpdateItem. User has administrator access

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, serverless-framework, serverless

The user has AdminitratorAccess. I am able to create and read the data from the dynamoDB.
I am using serverless tool and using `aws-go-mod` template.

Here is the serverless.yml

```
service: user-services-go
frameworkVersion: ">=1.28.0 <2.0.0"

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: go1.x
  stage: dev
  region: us-east-1
  environment:
    DYNAMODB_USER_TABLE: ${self:custom.dynamodb.userTable}
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - dynamodb:Query
        - dynamodb:Scan
        - dynamodb:GetItem
        - dynamodb:PutItem
      Resource: "*"

functions:
  updateUser:
    handler: bin/pkg/updateUser
    events:
      - http:
          method: put
          cors: true
          path: /v1/user/{username}
```

Thank you.

Comment: `- dynamodb:UpdateItem` is missing from the Action lists.

Comment: Okay, got it. Thank you. I was reading putitem as put request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the `dynamodb:UpddateItem` action from your `iamRoleStatements`.  Should read:

```
iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - dynamodb:Query
        - dynamodb:Scan
        - dynamodb:GetItem
        - dynamodb:PutItem
        - dynamodb:UpdateItem   # <--- ADD THIS LINE 
      Resource: "*"
```